# How to echo alert?

Tags: php

I want to use java script alert in php before data insertion. I am able to insert data to the database but echo won't do its job. This could be just a simple error but I just can't spot it :(

```
/// Java script
/// send data for insertion
$.get("tute7_add.php",{unit_code:unit_code,unit_name:unit_name,lecturer:lecturer,semester:semester}).done(function(data){
                    alert('You have added a unit successfully!');
                });
```

tute7_add.php

```
<?php
            // I Can't send alert!!
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                         alert('Don\'t have a record');
                    </script>";

            $code= $_GET['unit_code'];
            $name= $_GET['unit_name'];
            $lecturer= $_GET['lecturer'];
            $semester= $_GET['semester'];

            $query = "INSERT INTO units (`unit_code`,`unit_name`,`lecturer`,`semester`) VALUES ('$code','$name','$lecturer','$semester');";
            $mysqli->query($query);
    ?>
```

Comment: echo alert work fine, you want echo this alert if query have 0 result?

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: @Simone Rossaini  No, but I will need to echo some message based on different situations later.

Comment: [GET requests](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) are supposed to be Safe and Idempotent. Use a POST request if you want to insert data into a database.

Comment: You can return the response from `tute7_add.php`  based on different errors or success cases. you can make return format like array(sucess=><tru|false>,'msg'=><message>). this response you will get back in javascript and just alert response.msg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are requesting the URL using Ajax.

The `data` variable will have a chunk of HTML, including the script element, in it.

You *aren't doing anything* with the value of `data`. You're just ignoring it.

---

Generally when dealing with Ajax, you'll return the raw data in a format like JSON rather than using HTML. You can then process that with the client-side code.

e.g.

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
if (1) { # Use a real condition here
    echo json_encode([ "error" => "Don't have a record" ]);
    exit;
} else {
    # do database stuff and then…
    echo json_encode([ "success" => "Something something" ]);
    exit;
}
```

along with:

```
$.get("tute7_add.php", {
  unit_code,
  unit_name,
  lecturer,
  semester,
}).done(function (data) {
  if (done.success) {
    alert("You have added a unit successfully!");
  } else {
    alert(done.error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I will adopt your method. However, I still wanna know what is wrong with code. Did you spot any mistake?

Comment: @John — Quote: "You aren't doing anything with the value of data. You're just ignoring it."